# Regex for empty, whitespace or zero

Tags: javascript, regex

```
String = ""

String = "      "

String = "0"
```

I need regex to match all three scenario.

I got the first two as `/^$|\s+/`

How do I include the check for the zero?

Comment: Just curious, but why would you have strings that contain *only* whitespace or one single zero ?

Answer (score 6):

This will match the empty string, a single zero, or all whitespace:

```
/^(\s+|0)?$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eesXDtbrDP1238Sd)

Explanation:

- `/` delimiter
- `^` start of the string
- `(` start a group:

  - `\s+` one or more spaces
  - `|` or
  - `0` a zero
  - `)` end the group
- `?` match the preceding group zero or one times
- `$` end of the string
- `/` delimiter

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like :

```
/^[0\ ]*$/
```

Or :

```
/^(\ |0)*$/
```

If we don't want to match "00000[...]" or "0 0 0 0[...]" :

```
/^(\ *|0)$/
```

Comment: No need to escape the space.

Comment: @FelixKling Not mandatory, but I took this habit because of other technologies.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern will match any string that contains *any* whitespace (e.g. it would consider `"foo bar"` a match because of the space in the middle). It doesn't sound like this is what you want.

To match any string that contains only whitespace, a single `0`, or the empty string, use this:

```
/^\s*$|^0$/
```

Or this:

```
/^(\s*|0)$/
```